CometChat React UI screen share button missing on mobile
I have implemented cometchat react UI into my app and works just fine. I am able to do calls, chats, conversations, and messages just fine.
Whenever I call someone and in google chrome set responive mode to a mobile device, the share screen button disappears. If I do it on desktop mode, the screen share button appears and works fine.
Does screen share not work on mobile devices?
Desktop View
desktop view of screen share button
Mobile View
mobile view of missing screen share button
"react": "^18.2.0",
"@cometchat/calls-sdk-javascript": "^4.0.10",
"@cometchat/chat-sdk-javascript": "^4.0.10",
"@cometchat/chat-uikit-react": "^4.3.22",
"@cometchat/uikit-elements": "^4.3.17",
"@cometchat/uikit-resources": "^4.3.13",
"@cometchat/uikit-shared": "^4.3.19",
I have tried everything but there seems to be no way to get the button to show up when screen size is mobile
